# how to simple rebuild all aliases (friendly urls) to make them based on pagetitles? (MODX Revolution)

Tags: mod-rewrite, friendly-url, modx

I was creating a lot of documents and sub-documents on the documents-tree. But on Frontend Page there are their frendly url based on IDs. How to simple update that aliases and rewrite them to based on pagetitle? Iwas trying to put to columns

```
`alias`, `uri`
```

strings generated form page-title, but there was errors while flushing the modx cache. Do you know some add-on or SQL-query that simply do that job?

Comment: Have you activated "friendly URL" in your system settings?

Answer (score 0):

There is a switch in a System settings (I believe it is located somewhere in a FURL tab). This is almost mandatory setting of a MODx.